# Natural deduction (or similar) as TikZ tree

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm wondering if it's possible to make TikZ trees render in a way similar to natural deduction (proof) trees. Specifically I would like a tree which, rather than edges from parent to child, has lines horizontally (assuming the tree grows up or down) over each subtree.

I'm still new to TikZ and my best solution so far is to draw the tree without edges and use the `fit` library to construct bounding boxes for all the subtrees and then use the anchors of the bounding boxes to draw lines, hardly a satisfactory solution.

(I suspect I could be using chains, but as far as I can see you'd lose the convenient notation for trees.)

EDIT: If it was conveniently possible to traverse the tree nodes in a `\foreach` fashion the tedious part could at least be automated, would something like this be possible?

EDIT: I guess one could tweak the `level distance` so as to make the edged horizontal, this feels like rather a hack though.

EDIT: Here's an example of what I'm after

[image: example]

produced with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=up,level distance=4ex,
                  edge from parent/.code={},
                  level/.style={sibling distance=10em/#1}]
  \node (A) {A}
    child { node (B) {B}
      child { node (D) {D} }
      child { node (E) {E} } }
    child { node (C) {C}
      child { node (F) {F} }
      child { node (G) {G}
              child { node (H) {H} }
              child { node (I) {I} }
              child { node (J) {J} } } } ;
  \node (SubA) [fit=(B) (C)] {};
  \node (SubB) [fit=(D) (E)] {};
  \node (SubC) [fit=(F) (G)] {};
  \node (SubG) [fit=(H) (I) (J)] {};
  \foreach \root in {SubA, SubB, SubC, SubG}{
    \draw [thick] (\root.south west) -- (\root.south east);
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Could you point to an example of the kinds of results you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Check out some of the items here: [LaTeX for Logicians](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians). For trees generally of this sort, I recommend `tikz-qtree`.  There are a number of examples here on the site that might be of use: [tag:qtree] (make sure you choose the "newest" view of the tag's questions).

Comment: @Alan Minn: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already use tikz-qtree. The problem isn't with structuring the trees but with how they are drawn. Also I know there are packages around for drawing natural-deduction style trees, but I'm specifically interested in drawing them with tikz, and, even more specifically, using tikz's tree facility.

Comment: @Jake: Done, hope that clarified things.

Comment: @AlanMunn Any reason not to use one of the packages designed specifically for drawing these trees (which are naturally drawn child-first rather than parent-first)? Though I don't know what was around in 2011, but probably `bussproofs` at least, though not `ebproof` or `prftree`, for sure.

Comment: @cfr You're asking me to defend my thinking of 4 1/2 years ago... :) If you look at the edit history, the comment was made before there was any clear example posted (and I did first suggest LaTeX for Logicians as the first choice).

Comment: @AlanMunn Not really. I just wondered if there was a reason which you remembered. I perfectly prepared to accept that there may have been a reason you don't remember or no reason at all. I was just curious. I didn't examine the history so 'generally of this sort' sounded like 'looking like this'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the `edge from parent path` to yield horizontal lines. Below is a style that is adapted from the predefined style `edge from parent fork up` from the `trees` library:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    edge from parent path={
        (\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) 
        +(0pt,.5\tikzleveldistance)  
        -- (0pt,-.5\tikzleveldistance -| \tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor) 
        -- +(0.25cm,0pt) 
        -- +(-0.25cm,0pt)
    },
    grow'=up,level distance=4ex,
    level/.style={sibling distance=10em/#1}]
  \node (A) {A}
    child { node (B) {B}
      child { node (D) {D} }
      child { node (E) {E} } }
    child { node (C) {C}
      child { node (F) {F} }
      child { node (G) {G}
              child { node (H) {H} }
              child { node (I) {I} }
              child { node (J) {J} } } } ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! Somehow I'd managed to miss the `trees` library.

Comment: No problem. Note that you don't need to load the `trees` library with this example, I just used one of its styles as a starting point.